# How to unit test the value from a ChangeNotifier Provider state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a login/authentication feature set up in an app that I'm building. I'm struggling to find an example/conceptualize how I can unit test this.

## My auth provider service

I simplified some things.

```
import '../models/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

enum Status {
  Uninitialized,
  Authenticated,
  Unauthenticated,
  LoginError,
}

class MyAuth with ChangeNotifier {
  UserModel _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
  Status get status => _status;
  UserModel get user => _user;
  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
      await login(); //pseudo-code
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

## How I'm invoking

My `main.dart` is using MultiProvider:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyAuth()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
          initialRoute: '/',
        ));
  }
}
```

A downstream widget submits a form:

```
 _user = Provider.of<MyAuth>;
 ....
 return RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Log In');
  onPressed: () async {
   await _user.login('username', 'password');

 },
),
```

All of the login functionality works, what I want to be able to test is submitting the `login()` method then check the value of the `Status`. I would appreciate it if someone could give me a contained example of how to test this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `login()` method itself, you refer to it as "pseudo-code" but the whole test code would be made around it, so we need that code in order to help you.

But even without the `login()` code I can give you some hints on how to achieve your testing. First take a look at [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Basically you should exclude from your tests any side effects and volatile/slow systems, like network calls and database access.

To that end, you can make a fake API call that [Mocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) your login API and inject that fake object in your tests.

Lets pretend you are using FirebaseAuth as your auth API, so your code would become something like this:

`main.dart:`

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          // Inject a real FirebaseAuth for all other objects that wants it.
          Provider<FirebaseAuth>.value(value: FirebaseAuth.instance), 
          // We inject the real FirebaseAuth here so MyAuth can use it.
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MyAuth(FirebaseAuth.instance)),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
          initialRoute: '/',
        ));
  }
}
```

`login.dart:` (I don't know how you call it)

```dart
import '../models/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

enum Status {
  Uninitialized,
  Authenticated,
  Unauthenticated,
  LoginError,
}

class MyAuth with ChangeNotifier {
  // We inject the FirebaseAuth here:
  MyAuth(this._auth) : assert(_auth != null);

  final FirebaseAuth _auth;
  UserModel _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
  Status get status => _status;
  UserModel get user => _user;
  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
      // use _auth here!
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Now your test, using [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) should look something similar to this:

```dart
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockFirebaseAuth extends Mock implements FirebaseAuth {} 

MockFirebaseAuth mockAuth;

...

setUp(() {
 // configure how mockAuth should behave here:
  when(mockOldUser.reload()).thenAnswer((_) async {
    return null;
 });

test('User login', () async {
  // we create MyAuth with a fake instance of FirebaseAuth and inject it:
  var auth = MyAuth(mockAuth);
  await auth.login();
  expect(auth.status, equals(Status.Authenticated));
});
```

This is a blueprint on how to do it, I suggest you read how mocks work using Mockito, so you can create fake instances with predictable behavior under tests (like "throw an error" or "return a user"), and start to think differently when structuring your classes, using Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thank you for this, it makes sense and I'll test and follow up. The `login()` function is just making an HTTP POST request to an endpoint which returns a session token that gets stored in the `User` object.  The dependency injection makes sense, doing a "real" login test should be part of our integration tests (which I already have working).

Comment: Yes, thats correct, just inject a fake HTTP service.